# How to use last child as a parent in selenium javascript?

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I want to get input element of last child, this snippet is code of last child. I want to get text `Text Reply - Delete`.

```
<div class="priority-intent-div">
  <div class="row add-priority-intent-div">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <input type="hidden" name="priorityIntentId" value="5f8fb2f031f8a20a0cd6e2d1">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="intent-conditions">
           <button onclick="addIntentCondition(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="width: 100%">
              <span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Add Condition</button> 
         </div> 
           <label for="priorityIntentName" class="control-label">Intent Name</label>
           <input type="text" name="priorityIntentName" placeholder="Greeting" single="" maxlength="20" class="form-control maxlengthBadge" value="Text Reply - Delete" required="">
           <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
```

Trying to get last child using

```
let block = await driver.findElement(By.css('div.priority-list-tab > div.priority-intent-list > div:last-child'))
await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", block)
```

It's scroll down to last child `class="priority-intent-div">`. When trying to get text from the last child (text in input tag),  using

```
priority_intent_name = await block.findElement(By.xpath('div/div[1]/div/input'))
priority_intent_value = await priority_intent_name.getAttribute('value')
expect(priority_intent_value).to.be.eq(intent_name)
```

it given value of first child. Anyone can help? [image]

Comment: Just use `[name="priorityIntentName"]`

Comment: it give name of first priority-intent-div. I want to get value of last priority-intent-div, image attached on post

Comment: Then get all of them and use the last one.

Comment: how to get all of them and use the last one? I f I know, i would not post this question @pguardiario

Comment: I'm only suggesting css here, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let intentList = await driver.findElements(By.xpath(`//div[@class='priority-intent-list']`));
let lastList = intentList[intentList.lenght - 1];


let intentDiv = await intentList.findElements(By.xpath(`//div[@class='priority-intent-div']`));
let lastIntentDiv = intentDiv[intentDiv.lenght - 1]
let answer = await lastIntentDiv.findElement(By.xpath(`.//input[@type='text']`)).getAttribute('value')
```

or

```
let result = await driver.findelement(By.xpath(`//div[@class='priority-intent-list'][last()] //div[@class='priority-intent-div'][last()] //input[@type='text']`))
priority_intent_value = await result.getAttribute('value')
```

*find elements will give you a collection of elements, get the last one or use XPath to find the input directly, something like this `//input[(@value='Text Reply - Delete')]`
read this once: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html
*

Comment: I use `let block_row = await driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className("row add-priority-intent-div"))
        priority_intent_name = await block_row.findElements(By.name('priorityIntentName'))
       
        priority_intent_value = await priority_intent_name[priority_intent_name.length -1].getAttribute('value')
        expect(priority_intent_value).to.be.eq(intent_name)` but it given priority intent name of first child. @surya prakash. The value is on the last child, on attached image

Comment: trying yours, but still getting text from first intentDiv @Surya Prakash

Comment: can you please post you full HTML document, please

Comment: sorry I can not post full of HTML. On attached image, `priority-intent-list` have some child `priority-intent-div`. I want to get text from last `priority-intent-div`. @surya prakash

Comment: @herawatimanurung try to copy past my code. make sure you are using `findelements` and not `findelement`. put a break point in your `intentDiv`, it should be an array. you should be able to get the last one by getting the last index or write a `find` array method to find the specific element.

Comment: Trying 1st code, for priority-intent-list, I'm using findElement bcs only one, stil getting value of first child `priority-intent-div` , trying 2nd code got error `AssertionError: expected { Object (driver_, id_) } to equal 'Text Reply - Delete'`

Comment: @herawatimanurung if you want to find the last div, you need to use `findelements` and `findelement`. try to copy-paste my code or try to use the second one. if it is not working. I cannot help you, unless you are giving more input about your HTML dom